# How to import data from an ID in JSON file Firebase database

Tags: json, flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database, mobile-application

i'm trying to display the name, image and price of products based on the barcode stored as an id in a json file in firebase.
i have no errors but i'm not getting results and the progress indicator keeps running.
can someone please explain what the issue might be.
this is my code

```dart
class ProductDetails extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ProductDetailsState createState() => _ProductDetailsState();
}

class _ProductDetailsState extends State<ProductDetails> {
  late DatabaseReference _databaseReference;
  Map<String, dynamic>? _productDetails;

  @override
  void initState() {
    final id = "6130234001031";
    super.initState();
    _databaseReference =
        FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child('products').child(id);
    _databaseReference.onValue.listen((event) {
      final value = event.snapshot.value;
      if (value is Map<String, dynamic>) {
        setState(() {
          _productDetails = value;
        });
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Product Details'),
      ),
      body: _productDetails == null
          ? Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator())
          : Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Text(
                  _productDetails!['name'],
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 16),
                Text(
                  'Price: ${_productDetails!['price']}',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 16),
                Image.network(
                  _productDetails!['image'],
                  height: 200,
                ),
              ],
            ),
    );
  }
}
```

and this is my file products.json

```json
{
  "products": {
    "6130234001031": {
      "name": "Huile elio  Cevital 5L",
      "price": "650",
      "image": "https://www.tasshilfood.com/gla-adminer/uploads/article/full/623544822_30-01-2022_119941.jpg"
    },
    "4895122319422": {
      "name": "Batterie Uniross 1.5v AA",
      "price": "25",
      "image": "https://d1iv6qgcmtzm6l.cloudfront.net/product_galleries/lg_mnvrpSNKwlpX6eXohR8NGkk9MGlO7s5q5JhpE2dF.jpg"
    },
    "6130234002366": {
      "name": "Sucre Cristallisé Skor 1kg",
      "price": "90",
      "image": "https://www.tasshilfood.com/gla-adminer/uploads/article/full/899985951_31-01-2022_846987.jpg"
    },
    "6130492000562": {
      "name": "farine Mamade blé tendre",
      "price": "70",
      "image": "https://mama.dz/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/Farine_T45_FR-1.png"
    },
    "6130758000022": {
      "name": "Eau Guedila 1.5L",
      "price": "45",
      "image": "https://palma-market.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/08/GUEDILA-1.5L.jpg"
    },
    "6130384000809": {
      "name": "Cab sauce tomate - Amar benamor - 420g",
      "price": "180",
      "image": "https://toutdunet.fr/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/175.png"
    },
    "6133535000314": {
      "name": "papier mouchoire lovely plume",
      "price": "10",
      "image": "https://dz.openfoodfacts.org/images/products/613/353/500/0314/front_fr.8.full.jpg"
    }
  }
}
```

i tried to verify that the app is able to connect to the Firebase Realtime Database and retrieve data successfully. but i failed to access it `

Comment: Try with adding a log inside onValue listener to verify if you're getting data from firebase or not. Let me know if you're getting data then I can help more.

Comment: still no data was displayed

Comment: add a screenshot of your data on firebase

Comment: [firebase database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aufLD.png)